# How to determine if the view is for GET or POST in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MVC use action attributes to map the same view for http get or post:

```
 [HttpGet] 
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    ViewBag.Message = "Message";
    return View();
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(decimal a, decimal b, string operation)
 {
     ViewBag.Message = "Calculation Result:";
     ViewBag.Result = Calculation.Execute(a, b, operation);
     return View();
 }
```

In the MVC view, how can I determine if the view is for http get or http post?

---

in Views it is `IsPost`

```
@{
     var Message="";
     if(IsPost)
      {
            Message ="This is from the postback";
      }
       else
    {
            Message="This is without postback";
    }
}
```

PS: For dot net core it is:

```
Context.Request.Method == "POST"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod` stores current method. Or just `Request.HttpMethod` inside of view, but if you need to check this, there may be something wrong with your approach.

Think about using Post-Redirect-Get pattern to form reposting.

Comment: One scenario where you may actually need `IsPost` in your cshtml file is if you return a view that uses Html.Action in a form post. So the `[HttpPost]` route returns a view upon validation failure for example you probably need to pass in the posted Model like: `@Html.Action("FormFooPartial", "FormFoo", new { area = "", viewModel = Model })`.. otherwise you might loose some user input. For my case it seems I needed action methods for get and post.

Answer (score 10):

```
<% if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "GET") { %><!-- This is GET --><% }
   else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "POST")
      { %><!--This is POST--><%}
      else
      { %><!--Something another --><% } %
```

Answer (score 4):

For dot net core it is:

> Context.Request.Method == "POST"

Answer (score 1):

When checking for "*postback*" in `ASP.NET CORE 7`, you should also check if the model is *valid* like so:

```
    if(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && Context.Request.Method == "POST")
    {
        <p><strong>Yes I am Postback and Valid!</strong></p>
    }
```