# How can I get http-request type from view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am trying to do following:

There is a (view)model, which contains an array of currencies from some date range, also there are begin date and end date from this range. My thought is: when view is first requested (http-get) model will contain default data of `beginDate` and `endDate`, then user can change these values and if values are valid http-post is done. Then, while generating view-answer in case of http-post I insert in view some partial view, which will contain actually data (highcharts-graphic).

How can I do this, if possible. And what about this solution quality? Want to know patterns.

Comment: Got answer from this reference


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994707/how-to-determine-if-the-view-is-for-get-or-post-in-asp-net-mvc